# Young walnut is having trouble

Tags: walnut

I have planted this young walnut a some time ago.
[image]

Forget the yellow leaves .. It got way too much water last days :/
I am more concerned about the tree-top which turned black.

[image]

See on the picture, it's actually "open" in the middle. Should I cut the black part or fill the hole with something like clay or bee-wax ?

Many thx !

Comment: I imagine the roots have rotten and that's why the leaves are yellow. I would cut the black part off(and some non-black) but not put too much hope in the tree surviving. Posted as comment because I don't know what I'm talking about.